# WPF: Write rectangle depends on the mouse position using multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles, multibinding

How to write a WPF application that draws a rectangle. The size of the rectangle should depend on the mouse position. The mouse pointer is always at one corner of the rectangle.
The rectangle is always centered.

**It should look something like this:**

[image] [image]

**This is My Code:**

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" x:Name="window1" Height="450" Width="800" MouseMove="Grid1_MouseMove">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SizeConverter x:Key="sizeConv" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" 
       Width="{Binding ElementName=window1, Path=MousePos.X}" 
       Height="{Binding ElementName=window1, Path=MousePos.Y}" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Point _mousePos;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public Point MousePos
        {
            get { return _mousePos; }
            set
            {
                _mousePos = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MousePos"));
            }
        }


        private void Grid1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MousePos = e.GetPosition(window1);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Be aware that "*The size **and position** of the rectangle should depend on the mouse position*" and "*The rectangle is **always centered***" are contradicting requirements.

Comment: @clemens Thx, didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you want to draw a rectangle at the center of the window. The size of this rectangle is calculated based on the mouse pointer position.
So that the mouse pointer is always in one of the corner of the rectangle.

[image]

The height of the rectangle is

```
rect.Height = Math.Abs(mousePosition.Y - container.ActualHeight / 2) * 2
```

The width of the rectangle is

```
rect.Width = Math.Abs(mousePosition.X - container.ActualWidth / 2) * 2
```

You need to create a ViewModel that contains properties

```
public class MyRectContainerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private double _actualHeight;
    public double ActualHeight
    {
        get { return  _actualHeight; }
        set 
        {
            if (_actualHeight != value)
            {
                _actualHeight = value;
                RecalculateSize();
            }
        }
    }

    private double _actualWidth;

    public double ActualWidth
    {
        get { return _actualWidth; }
        set
        {
            if (_actualWidth != value)
            {
                _actualWidth = value;
                RecalculateSize();
            }
        }
    }


    private Point _mousePosition;

    public Point MousePosition
    {
        get { return _mousePosition; }
        set 
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_mousePosition))
            {
                _mousePosition = value;
                RecalculateSize();
            }
        }
    }

    public double RectHeight { get; private set; }
    public double RectWidth { get; private set; }


    private void RecalculateSize()
    {
        RectWidth = Math.Abs(MousePosition.X - ActualWidth / 2) * 2;
        RectHeight = Math.Abs(MousePosition.Y - ActualHeight / 2) * 2;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RectHeight));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RectWidth));
    }
}
```

The DataContext of the rectangle is the MyRectContainerViewModel.

If you are using MVVM, you need to find a way to update ActualHeight and ActualWidth.
[ActualHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualHeight)

> Although it has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight does not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.

Idem for the Mouse Position. You can use interactivity
Example of use [Binding Mouse position](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/how-to-get-mouse-cursor-position-in-wpf-mvvm-applications/)